# how to send an embed privately after i run a button?

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I would have a problem with modals.
I want that when someone executes a modal in the log the embed is sent with the accepted or rejected button and up to here everything is fine.
when a staff accepts or refuses I want the embed of the result to be sent to the person who performed the modal.
**how can I do?**
this is the modal code:

```
    client.on("messageCreate", (message, interaction) => {
    if(message.content == "!bando"){
        const bando = new MessageEmbed()
        .setColor("#037bfc")
        .setTitle("MODULO BANDO STAFF")
        .setDescription(`Se vorresti diventare staff, segui le regole\n del bando in <#995108403330416753> e poi premi il bottone qua sotto`)
        .setTimestamp()
        .setFooter({ text: "Developed by @Wrld#0095", iconURL: "https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/987458307092545568/995114362748547183/logo-wrld.gif"})

        const row = new MessageActionRow()
            .addComponents(
                new MessageButton()
                    .setCustomId('bando')
                    .setLabel('Modulo bando')
                    .setStyle('PRIMARY')
                    .setEmoji(''),
            );

        message.channel.send({embeds: [bando], components: [row]})
    }
})



client.on('interactionCreate', async interaction => {
    if (!interaction.isButton()) return;
    if (interaction.customId === 'bando') {
        // Create the modal
        const modal = new Modal()
            .setCustomId('modalBando')
            .setTitle('MODULO BANDO');
        
        const nome = new TextInputComponent()
            .setCustomId('nome')
            .setLabel("Nome")
            .setStyle('SHORT');
        const eta = new TextInputComponent()
            .setCustomId('eta')
            .setLabel("Età")
            .setStyle('SHORT');
        const motivo = new TextInputComponent()
            .setCustomId('motivo')
            .setLabel("Perchè vorresti diventare staff?")
            .setStyle('PARAGRAPH');
        const mansione = new TextInputComponent()
            .setCustomId('mansione')
            .setLabel("Che ruolo vorresti ricoprire?")
            .setStyle('SHORT');
        
        const firstActionRow = new MessageActionRow().addComponents(nome);
        const secondActionRow = new MessageActionRow().addComponents(eta);
        const thirdActionRow = new MessageActionRow().addComponents(motivo);
        const fourthActionRow = new MessageActionRow().addComponents(mansione);
        modal.addComponents(firstActionRow, secondActionRow, thirdActionRow, fourthActionRow);

        await interaction.showModal(modal);

    }


   
});

client.on("interactionCreate", async interaction => {

    if (!interaction.isModalSubmit()) return;

    if (interaction.customId === 'modalBando') {
        
        const author = interaction.member
        const bandoInviato = new MessageEmbed()
        .setColor("#037bfc")
        .setTitle("MODULO BANDO STAFF")
        .setDescription(`Salve, il suo bando è stato inviato.\n Presto le comunicheremo l'esito.`)
        .setTimestamp()
        .setFooter({ text: "Developed by @Wrld#0095", iconURL: "https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/987458307092545568/995114362748547183/logo-wrld.gif"})
        await author.send({ embeds: [bandoInviato]});
        
        const nome = interaction.fields.getTextInputValue('nome');
    const eta = interaction.fields.getTextInputValue('eta');
    const motivo = interaction.fields.getTextInputValue('motivo');
    const mansione = interaction.fields.getTextInputValue('mansione');
    const logBando = interaction.guild.channels.cache.get("995105468341026866");
    const bandoLog = new MessageEmbed()
        .setColor("#037bfc")
        .setTitle("MODULO BANDO STAFF")
        .setDescription(`Bando eseguito da ${interaction.user.tag}`)
        .addFields(
            { name: 'Nome', value: nome, inline: false },
            { name: 'Età', value: eta, inline: false },
            { name: 'Perchè vorresti diventare staff?', value: motivo, inline: false },
            { name: 'Che ruolo vorresti ricoprire?', value: mansione, inline: false },
        )
        .setTimestamp()
        .setFooter({ text: "Developed by @Wrld#0095", iconURL: "https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/987458307092545568/995114362748547183/logo-wrld.gif"})

        const esitoBando = new MessageActionRow()
            .addComponents(
                new MessageButton()
                    .setCustomId('accettato')
                    .setLabel('Accetta')
                    .setStyle('SUCCESS')
                    .setEmoji('✔'),
                    new MessageButton()
                    .setCustomId('rifiutato')
                    .setLabel('Rifiuta')
                    .setStyle('DANGER')
                    .setEmoji('❌'),
            );
        await logBando.send({ embeds: [bandoLog], components: [esitoBando]});
        
    }

    if(!interaction.isButton()) return;
    if(interaction.customId == "accettato"){
        const accettato = new MessageEmbed()
        .setColor("#037bfc")
        .setTitle("BANDO ACCETTATO")
        .setDescription(`Salve, il suo bando è stato accettato.\n Apra un <#995105177403142174>e comunica gli orari disponibili\n per effettuare il colloquio.`)
        .setTimestamp()
        .setFooter({ text: "Developed by @Wrld#0095", iconURL: "https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/987458307092545568/995114362748547183/logo-wrld.gif"})

        await author.send({ embeds: [accettato]})
    } else if(interaction.customId == "rifiutato"){

        const rifiutato = new MessageEmbed()
        .setColor("#037bfc")
        .setTitle("BANDO RIFIUTATO")
        .setDescription(`Salve, il suo bando è stato rifiutato.\n Ritenta alle prossime candidature.`)
        .setTimestamp()
        .setFooter({ text: "Developed by @Wrld#0095", iconURL: "https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/987458307092545568/995114362748547183/logo-wrld.gif"})

        await author.send({ embeds: [rifiutato]})
    }
    
})
```

Answer (score 0):

I refactored your code, you don't need more than one listener of each type, but this should work for you.
I added a component to the embed that is created when the modal is submitted. That component is used to locate the original member who created it.

```js
client.on("messageCreate", (message, interaction) => {
    if (message.content === "!bando") {
        const bando = new MessageEmbed()
            .setColor("#037bfc")
            .setTitle("MODULO BANDO STAFF")
            .setDescription(`Se vorresti diventare staff, segui le regole\n del bando in <#995108403330416753> e poi premi il bottone qua sotto`)
            .setTimestamp()
            .setFooter({
                text: "Developed by @Wrld#0095",
                iconURL: "https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/987458307092545568/995114362748547183/logo-wrld.gif"
            })

        const row = new MessageActionRow()
            .addComponents(
                new MessageButton()
                .setCustomId('bando')
                .setLabel('Modulo bando')
                .setStyle('PRIMARY')
                .setEmoji(''),
            );

        message.channel.send({
            embeds: [bando],
            components: [row]
        });
    }
});



client.on('interactionCreate', async interaction => {
    const author = interaction.member;
    let member2Send = interaction.guild.members.cache.get(interaction.message.embeds[0].author.name);

    if (interaction.isButton()) {
        if (interaction.customId === 'bando') {
            const modal = new Modal()
                .setCustomId('modalBando')
                .setTitle('MODULO BANDO');

            const nome = new TextInputComponent()
                .setCustomId('nome')
                .setLabel("Nome")
                .setStyle('SHORT');
            const eta = new TextInputComponent()
                .setCustomId('eta')
                .setLabel("Età")
                .setStyle('SHORT');
            const motivo = new TextInputComponent()
                .setCustomId('motivo')
                .setLabel("Perchè vorresti diventare staff?")
                .setStyle('PARAGRAPH');
            const mansione = new TextInputComponent()
                .setCustomId('mansione')
                .setLabel("Che ruolo vorresti ricoprire?")
                .setStyle('SHORT');

            const firstActionRow = new MessageActionRow().addComponents(nome);
            const secondActionRow = new MessageActionRow().addComponents(eta);
            const thirdActionRow = new MessageActionRow().addComponents(motivo);
            const fourthActionRow = new MessageActionRow().addComponents(mansione);
            modal.addComponents(firstActionRow, secondActionRow, thirdActionRow, fourthActionRow);

            await interaction.showModal(modal);

        } else if (interaction.customId === "accettato") {
            if (member2Send) {
                    const accettato = new MessageEmbed()
                    .setColor("#037bfc")
                    .setTitle("BANDO ACCETTATO")
                    .setDescription(`Salve, il suo bando è stato accettato.\n Apra un <#995105177403142174>e comunica gli orari disponibili\n per effettuare il colloquio.`)
                    .setTimestamp()
                    .setFooter({
                        text: "Developed by @Wrld#0095",
                        iconURL: "https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/987458307092545568/995114362748547183/logo-wrld.gif"
                    })

                await member2Send.send({
                    embeds: [accettato]
                });
            }

        } else if (interaction.customId === "rifiutato") {
            if (member2Send){
                    const rifiutato = new MessageEmbed()
                    .setColor("#037bfc")
                    .setTitle("BANDO RIFIUTATO")
                    .setDescription(`Salve, il suo bando è stato rifiutato.\n Ritenta alle prossime candidature.`)
                    .setTimestamp()
                    .setFooter({
                        text: "Developed by @Wrld#0095",
                        iconURL: "https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/987458307092545568/995114362748547183/logo-wrld.gif"
                    })

                await member2Send.send({
                    embeds: [rifiutato]
                });
            }
        }
    }

    if (interaction.isModalSubmit()) {
        if (interaction.customId === 'modalBando') {

            const bandoInviato = new MessageEmbed()
                .setColor("#037bfc")
                .setAuthor({
                    name: author.user.id
                })
                .setTitle("MODULO BANDO STAFF")
                .setDescription(`Salve, il suo bando è stato inviato.\n Presto le comunicheremo l'esito.`)
                .setTimestamp()
                .setFooter({
                    text: "Developed by @Wrld#0095",
                    iconURL: "https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/987458307092545568/995114362748547183/logo-wrld.gif"
                })
            await author.send({
                embeds: [bandoInviato]
            });

            const nome = interaction.fields.getTextInputValue('nome');
            const eta = interaction.fields.getTextInputValue('eta');
            const motivo = interaction.fields.getTextInputValue('motivo');
            const mansione = interaction.fields.getTextInputValue('mansione');
            const logBando = interaction.guild.channels.cache.get("995105468341026866");
            const bandoLog = new MessageEmbed()
                .setColor("#037bfc")
                .setTitle("MODULO BANDO STAFF")
                .setDescription(`Bando eseguito da ${interaction.user.tag}`)
                .addFields({
                    name: 'Nome',
                    value: nome,
                    inline: false
                }, {
                    name: 'Età',
                    value: eta,
                    inline: false
                }, {
                    name: 'Perchè vorresti diventare staff?',
                    value: motivo,
                    inline: false
                }, {
                    name: 'Che ruolo vorresti ricoprire?',
                    value: mansione,
                    inline: false
                }, )
                .setTimestamp()
                .setFooter({
                    text: "Developed by @Wrld#0095",
                    iconURL: "https://cdn.discordapp.com/attachments/987458307092545568/995114362748547183/logo-wrld.gif"
                });

            const esitoBando = new MessageActionRow()
                .addComponents(
                    new MessageButton()
                    .setCustomId('accettato')
                    .setLabel('Accetta')
                    .setStyle('SUCCESS')
                    .setEmoji('✔'),
                    new MessageButton()
                    .setCustomId('rifiutato')
                    .setLabel('Rifiuta')
                    .setStyle('DANGER')
                    .setEmoji('❌'),
                );

            await logBando.send({
                embeds: [bandoLog],
                components: [esitoBando]
            });
        }
    }
});
```